# Why do Docker containers sometimes start to slow down when I use internet via PCI?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

However they never slow down when using the internet via USB of my smartphone. Internet connection via PCI is stable and speed is fast.

`docker stats` command returns:

```
CONTAINER ID   CPU %     MEM USAGE / LIMIT     MEM %     NET I/O           BLOCK I/O     PIDS
255c1a6063d8   0.14%     8.449MiB / 15.42GiB   0.05%     5.77MB / 6.34MB   6.5MB / 0B    3
a83bbefd9a3a   1.26%     843.8MiB / 15.42GiB   5.34%     122MB / 26MB      25.5MB / 0B   56
1313e1a86d02   0.00%     16.59MiB / 15.42GiB   0.11%     18.8kB / 0B       492kB / 0B    11
2fed7b3644ce   0.43%     161.1MiB / 15.42GiB   1.02%     18.7MB / 98.9MB   18.4MB / 0B   38
899e14fb8aef   0.09%     23.78MiB / 15.42GiB   0.15%     993kB / 21.9MB    1.01MB / 0B   10
e5796185b87d   0.00%     7.254MiB / 15.42GiB   0.05%     18.8kB / 0B       2.51MB / 0B   9
```

OS Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS

Docker version 23.0.3, build 3e7cbfd

I do not know what the problem is. What should I check for?